# I created an application in VS Code, and everything is OK on my localhost but it doesn't work on Heroku:

Tags: python, flask, heroku, server, http-status-code-500

When im hit  open on heroku im taking 500 error and at logs, I took this:

```
2023-04-10T06:54:15.755428+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fotis-app.herokuapp.com request_id=9e39297e-3d59-4b73-821f-a6b44530dd14 fwd="212.205.99.28" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=404 bytes=393 protocol=https
2023-04-10T06:54:15.756402+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.42.90 - - [10/Apr/2023:06:54:15 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "https://fotis-app.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193773+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-04-10 06:55:22,190] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193794+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193796+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193796+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.dialect.do_execute(
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193797+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 593, in do_execute
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193797+00:00 app[web.1]:     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193797+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: blog_posts.author_id
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193798+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193799+00:00 app[web.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193799+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193799+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193800+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193800+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193801+00:00 app[web.1]:                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193801+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193801+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193802+00:00 app[web.1]:          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193802+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193802+00:00 app[web.1]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193802+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193803+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise value
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193803+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193803+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193803+00:00 app[web.1]:          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193804+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193804+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193804+00:00 app[web.1]:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193804+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/main.py", line 76, in get_all_posts
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193805+00:00 app[web.1]:     posts = BlogPost.query.all()
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193805+00:00 app[web.1]:             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193805+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3346, in all
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193805+00:00 app[web.1]:     return list(self)
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193806+00:00 app[web.1]:            ^^^^^^^^^^
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193806+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3508, in __iter__
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193806+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self._execute_and_instances(context)
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193806+00:00 app[web.1]:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193806+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3533, in _execute_and_instances
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193807+00:00 app[web.1]:     result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193807+00:00 app[web.1]:              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193807+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1011, in execute
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193807+00:00 app[web.1]:     return meth(self, multiparams, params)
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193807+00:00 app[web.1]:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193808+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193808+00:00 app[web.1]:     return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193808+00:00 app[web.1]:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193808+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1124, in _execute_clauseelement
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193809+00:00 app[web.1]:     ret = self._execute_context(
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193809+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193809+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1316, in _execute_context
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193809+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._handle_dbapi_exception(
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193809+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1510, in _handle_dbapi_exception
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193810+00:00 app[web.1]:     util.raise_(
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193810+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in raise_
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193810+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise exception
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193810+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193810+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.dialect.do_execute(
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193810+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 593, in do_execute
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193811+00:00 app[web.1]:     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193811+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: blog_posts.author_id
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193818+00:00 app[web.1]: [SQL: SELECT blog_posts.id AS blog_posts_id, blog_posts.author_id AS blog_posts_author_id, blog_posts.title AS blog_posts_title, blog_posts.subtitle AS blog_posts_subtitle, blog_posts.date AS blog_posts_date, blog_posts.body AS blog_posts_body, blog_posts.img_url AS blog_posts_img_url 
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193818+00:00 app[web.1]: FROM blog_posts]
2023-04-10T06:55:22.193828+00:00 app[web.1]: (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
2023-04-10T06:55:22.194606+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.19.176 - - [10/Apr/2023:06:55:22 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
2023-04-10T06:55:22.194130+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=fotis-app.herokuapp.com request_id=87e90fa6-00a8-41d4-bc7c-f24ae7acd563 fwd="212.205.99.28" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=500 bytes=463 protocol=https
```

I was expected to run everything normally.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: blog_posts.author_id` check if this column is present.

Comment: well, the log is clear `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: blog_posts.author_id` when you execute `SELECT blog_posts.id AS blog_posts_id, blog_posts.author_id AS blog_posts_author_id, blog_posts.title AS blog_posts_title, blog_posts.subtitle AS blog_posts_subtitle, blog_posts.date AS blog_posts_date, blog_posts.body AS blog_posts_body, blog_posts.img_url AS blog_posts_img_url FROM blog_posts`

Comment: My guess is there's at least one DB migration you haven't run on the Heroku DB ... specifically one to add the `author` FK to your `blog_posts` model.